# WWW domain on azure

Tags: azure, dns

I am trying to configure a www domain on azure. I want to have website under this domain. My domain is "legia.fitness". I have created the DNS zone as follows:
[image: Azure DNS Zone]

On this picture you see 4 DNS servers. I have delegated my domain that I bought at home.pl to those servers:
[image: Home.pl domain delegation]

And this doesn't work. When I try to browse legia.fitness I get "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your Azure DNS zone does not have any `A` or `CNAME` records for `www` or `@` so the name cannot be resolved to an IP address.

Add a new `A` record with the label `@` set to the IP address of your Azure website, and another `A` record with the label `www` also set to the same IP address.

Alternatively, create `CNAME` records (both `@` and `www`) and set them to your Azure Website's name (e.g. `yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net`). `CNAME` records are aliases of existing `A` or `CNAME` records, but are slower to resolve which is why I prefer `A` records.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't directed the domain anywhere yet.

You have a DNS zone that works. I can see the SOA records on Dig web interface.

Now you have to add CNAME/A records to the DNS zone to direct the traffic to where you want it.

Here is a guide for Azure Web Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name

If you use something else, you'll need to find its guide.

Comment: My DNS records now looks like this: https://ibb.co/fsG31F but now I am getting 404 error. I don't have any application uploaded yet.

Comment: Looks good, they are in DNS now. Have you added the custom domain on the Web App?

Comment: I didn't upload any app yet to azure. But if I browse to http://bsiemasz.azurewebsites.net/ I don't get any 404 error.

Comment: The only reason you would get a 404 then is if you didn't configure the custom domain on the Web App.